# App rejected because of missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, app-store

I try to add my app to app store. I submitted the app, but it was rejected (`metadata rejection`). I got an message that they found camera usage in `info.plist` but that they do not know where I use the camera .

I explained them where I use the camera and that was ok. But then is the app rejected because of **missing Info.plist key**. The missing keys are `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` and `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`. But the problem is that my app doesn't use any of those two. Maybe some of the dependencies??

I can add `key value` pair to `info.plist`. For example

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs to use your calendar.</string>

<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs to use your bluetooth.</string>
```

But what if I get the same question as for the camera? I can't answer on it, because I do not know which of my dependencies uses bluetooth or calendar.

Does anyone know how can I check what attempts to access privacy-sensitive data (in this example `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` and `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`)?

Comment: Your libs might need to use them, thats probably why

Answer (score 0):

When using the app, it should appear in the logs when the app tries to access any of them.